# Why does my website look different in Safari and how can I fix it?

Tags: html, css, safari, position

My site is [www.elansz.com](http://www.elansz.com). It looks good in Google Chrome but in Safari a lot of the elements are positioned to the right too far. How can I fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need this on your site

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

Comment: I have installed it and it still doesn't look the same on Safari... Any ideas?